# Only show an element when scrolling below the fold

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a fixed position element that I want to conditionally show when the user scrolls below the viewport fold. Specifically, I have a link affixed to the bottom of the page that will send the user to the top of the page. There is no reason for the link to appear unless the `body` is greater than `100vh` and the user has scrolled below the initial fold. Is this possible only using CSS?

Diagram:

```
 _______________________
|                       |
| document text         |
| document text         |
| document text         |
| document text         |
| document text         |
|-----------------------| <-- viewport fold
| document text         |
| document text         |
| document text         |
|                 Top ↑ | <-- only show this link when below the fold
|_______________________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS. It is only possible with Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot provide miracles! But we *can* help if you are willing to use javascript. I'd even provide an example for you :)

Comment: Nah, I know how to do it in JS. Thanks anyway.